# Do these definitions capture the notion of extending a model to a model?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

When one say that a model $(M,\in^M) $ extends to a model $(N,\in^N)$, does that mean the following?

1. $ \ M \subseteq N$
2. $ (\in^N)^M \ = \ \in^M$

Where: $R^X = \{(a,b) \mid (a,b) \in R \land a \in X \land b \in X\}$

Or does it mean the following?

There exists $f$ such that:

$1. f: M \hookrightarrow N \\ 2. (\in^N)^{f``M} = f``^3 \in^M $

Where: $f``X = f``^1 X = \{f(x) \mid x \in X \} \\ f``^{n+1} X = \{f``^n x \mid x \in X \}, \text { for } n \geq 1$.

All relations formalized as sets of Kuratowski ordered pairs.

Now in the context of forcing if one says that a model $M$ extends to a model $M[G]$ (both in the language of set theory), then is it the first definition that is meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first definition defines: $M$ is substructure of $N$.

The second definitions defines: $f$ is an embedding of $M$ embeds into $N$.

The latter is equivalent to saying that $f$ is an isomorphism between $M$ and $f``M$ and $f``M$ is a substructure of $N$.

Comment: So a forcing extension of M is a superstructure of M?

Comment: The pedantic answer is: it depends on the formal definition of $M[G]$. It is safer to say that $M$ embeds into $M[G]$. But it is common to confuse $M$ with its image in $M[G]$ and to say that $M$ is a substructure of $M[G]$.

Comment: Most of the forcing material I've read, stipulate that $M \subset M[G]$. So, to me, by $M $ has a forcing extension to $M[G]$, it appears to mean the first definition, i.e. $M$ is a substructure of $M[G]$, together with the rest of details of forcing.